# How do you make different JSON keybinds than just numbers? (for example: "BackKey": 96 and i want to change that to like left arrow key)

Tags: json

So I am currently stuck on how to fix this. I found this script online but I want to learn how to change these numbers into something I understand more clearly. I've looked online but can't really find anything much (I may have not searched the right things).

Currently, my JSON script is:

```
    "KeyBindings": {
      "BackKey": 96,
      "DownKey": 98,
      "LeftKey": 100,
      "MenuToggle": 116,
      "RightKey": 102,
      "SelectKey": 101,
      "UpKey": 104
    },
```

Is there like a website with a list of keybindings for like arrow left etc?
Thanks (I'm quite new to json at the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the JSON-keys are just descriptions of app behavior instead of keyboard key type.

For example your Select Key seems to be Numpad 5. These KeyCode numbers are processed by Javascript.

Look up codes at https://keycode.info/

Comment: There's another tool that displays a bit more information, https://keyjs.dev 